# Generate YAML or JSON file for REST API

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, swagger

I am using swagger to document my REST API. But i am using swagger annotation in my code like @API, @APIOperation etc. But i dont want to add these annotation. Is there any way to generate YAML or JSON file for REST API then use these files to describes, document and visualize REST API.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40661283/113116) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30417089/113116) Q&As which mention the [JAX-RS Analyzer](https://github.com/sdaschner/jaxrs-analyzer-maven-plugin) Maven plugin. Does this help?